# persistent popup icon - like a paw print

Tags: icons

There is a pop-up that regularly displays. The image looks an animal paw print ... five quadrilaterals radiating outward, surrounding a central irregular quadrilateral (concave top surface), and below a horizontal bar that scrolls left to right.

[image]

What is this signaling?

Comment: Something to do with brightness?

Comment: Brightness applet

Comment: Is there also any key on you pc with this icon? Are you using a DELL computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for the suggestions. I found it ... it is the backlit keyboard icon for the Dell XPS. I don't know why it keeps flashing, but seems to be much discussion on Dell websites related to problems with this function.

the icon is similar to the image on the F6 key on the keyboard.